# How do I compare an input to data that's already in an SQLite3 table?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to compare a user input with data that's already in a table?

So far I've done the following code

```
db_info = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usersTable");
    if login_user in db_info:
        game()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Invalid Details", "Inputted details are invalid!")
```

When I run this, nothing happens so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.
Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: What is the definition of the table and what is `login_user`?

Comment: The table has 3 columns which are username, password and score. Username and password and score are stored in the database, e.g. username: Vlad1 and password: pass123. login_user is what a user types to try and login. So I need to compare what's in the table to login_user.

Comment: Ok for the table description even if it should be in the question itself. But is `login_user` only the user name, or a (user, password) sequence?

Comment: It is only the username. But in the meantime I fixed the issue. Now my problem is an incorrect if statement which I'll take care of myself. Thanks for the help and support!

Answer (score 1):

The common way to find a username in a database is to use a where clause:

```
db_info = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM usersTable WHERE username=?",
                         [login_user]).fetchone()

if db_info is not None:
    # check password
    game()
else:
    messagebox.showerror("Invalid Details", "Inputted details are invalid!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`db_info` is a cursor object therefore this `login_user in db_info` will always evaluate to false.

From the [python sqlite 3 API interface doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

> To retrieve data after executing a SELECT statement, you can either treat the cursor as an iterator, call the cursor’s fetchone() method to retrieve a single matching row, or call fetchall() to get a list of the matching rows.

There are plenty of examples in the doc that will inform you how to get the data so you can construct the right logical test.